# Updating existing Image and Table fields

Tags: java, itext

I have a pdf built with LiveCycle Designer, I am easily able to update all TextFields using iText 5.4.3.  My issue is how do I update the existing ImageField and access a Table object?

I have obtained the position of the image field and am able to add the image onto the form, then remove the image field.

```
Rectangle rect = acroFields.getFieldPositions("TopmostSubform[0].Page5[0].processFlowImage[0]")
        .get(0).position;
String realPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");
Image img = Image.getInstance(realPath + wsSelected.getImage());
// use scalePercent as images are process flow diagrams and image 
// ratios are not consistent and making them absolute causes distortion
img.scalePercent((float) 47.0);
img.setAbsolutePosition(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());
stamper.getOverContent(5).addImage(img);
```

While this works, I would think there would, or should, be the ability to get the image field and populate with an InputStream or file.

Another issue is when working with Pre-defined tables on the form.  I can get the field names and update the appropriate cells.

However, I have not been able to find any examples of obtaining the table, as a table object, and adding new rows.  I can obtain the location, create a new PdfPTable and stamp it onto the form with the data.  This will not work.  The table will have a dynamic number of rows, based on db data.  It is in a flowable layout, between pre-defined text and headers.  The form (template) is pre-built and provided as a template.  The form is populated with DB values and some user input from a JSF application, and presented back to the user as a finished interface agreement.

My thought is, if I can't access the table object and it's attributes (rows, columns, cells) I would need to read the form, effectively line by line, create and insert the dynamic tables to the output stream when and where they need to be, then continue reading the form and stamping the end result to a new form.

Comment: for your dynamic table, you can define the xml schema and data bindings using the livecycle designer. write out your database data into xml according to the schema and import it back to the pdf. the dynamic table will have the rows and columns when you open the pdf.

Comment: I don't think it's a dynamic table because if it was, `getFieldPositions()` wouldn't work. I think it's a static XFA form and that the AcroFields are used. In that case, the question is void: there is no dynamic table.

Comment: I'm using the getFieldPositions() to obtain the location of the image field.  The table was created in LiveCycle using the wizard and selecting "Body rows vary depending on data".  I think I may have found an answer.  Using your examples in chapter 8, iText in Action, I see that it's an XFA form.  I have populated some of the fields in Acrobat Pro, including the image, and exported to XML.  I think I will need to use the XfaForm methods to populate the data within the form.  Appreciate the feedback.